ruby - ovirt-engine-sdk-ruby - Error during SSO authentication, access_denied: Cannot authenticate user
Ruby ovirt-engine-sdk is not working after mac update.
Current mac version: Sonama - Version 14.6.1
Getting following Error when i try to connect ovirt engine:
create_access_token': Error during SSO authentication: access_denied: Cannot authenticate user 'user@domain.com': Unable to log in. **Verify your login information or contact the system administrator.. (OvirtSDK4::AuthError)
  ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/connection.rb:476:in `create_access_token': Error during SSO authentication: access_denied: Cannot authenticate user 'user@domain.com': Unable to log in. **Verify your login information or contact the system administrator.. (OvirtSDK4::AuthError)**
    from /Users/077503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/connection.rb:646:in `internal_send'
    from /Users/77503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/connection.rb:202:in `block in send'
    from /Users/77503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/connection.rb:202:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/77503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/connection.rb:202:in `send'
    from /Users/77503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/service.rb:194:in `internal_get'
    from /Users/77503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/services.rb:36365:in `list 

Code:
connection = OvirtSDK4::Connection.new(
  url:      'https://xxx.example.com/ovirt-engine/api',
  username: 'xxx@domain.com',
  password: 'xxx',
  debug:    true,
  insecure: true)


Maybe your certificates got messed up during the update? The documentation states: "If neither [ca_file] nor the ca_certs options are provided, then the system wide CA certificates store is used." Either that or as the error suggests your credentials are wrong.

I tried using ca_file and i tried with insecure: true. None of these conditions are working. I'm able to generate token from postman but not able to generate with ruby sdk
How do i check ovirt sdk's campatibility with engine(engine version is 4.5.4-1.0.31)

I am sorry I am not familiar with oVirt at all but it appears that 4.6.0 is the correct model for that version according to this https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine/releases/tag/ovirt-engine-4.5.4. Can you see if the token from postman works? e.g. Connection.new(token: POSTMAN_TOKEN_HERE)

I tried this approach.. It is working for get operations but post operations it shows an error  Fault reason is "Request syntactically incorrect.". Fault detail is "For correct usage, see: https://xxx.xxx.com/ovirt-engine/apidoc#services/clusters/methods/add". HTTP response code is 400. (OvirtSDK4::Error)
I don't think any with the payload  - https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-engine-sdk-ruby/blob/master/sdk/examples/add_vm.rb
